# email settings per environment not working

Tags: config, emails, environments

I'm trying to set this up changing `config/app.php`

with

```php
'dev' => [
        'components' => [
            'mailer' => function () {
                // Get the stored email settings
                $settings = App::mailSettings();

                // Override the transport adapter class
                $settings->transportType = Smtp::class;

                // Override the transport adapter settings
                $settings->transportSettings = [
                    'host' => getenv('SMTP_HOSTNAME'),
                    'port' => getenv('SMTP_PORT'),
                    'useAuthentication' => (bool)getenv('SMTP_USE_AUTH') ?: true,
                    'username' => getenv('SMTP_USERNAME'),
                    'password' => getenv('SMTP_PASSWORD'),
                    'encryptionMethod' => getenv('SMTP_ENCRYPTION_METHOD') ?: null, // 'ssl' or 'tls' or nothing
                    'timeout' => getenv('SMTP_TIMEOUT') ?: 10,
                ];

                // Create a Mailer component config with these settings
                $config = App::mailerConfig($settings);

                // Instantiate and return it
                return Craft::createObject($config);
            },
        ],
    ],

    'production' => [
        'components' => [
            'mailer' => function () {
                // Get the stored email settings
                $settings = Craft::$app->systemSettings->getEmailSettings();

                // Override the transport adapter class
                $settings->transportType = MailgunAdapter::class;

                // Override the transport adapter settings
                $settings->transportSettings = [
                    'domain' => App::env('CRAFT_MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
                    'apiKey' => App::env('CRAFT_MAILGUN_API_KEY'),
                ];

                return MailerHelper::createMailer($settings);
            }
        ]
    ],
```

The control panel tells me `It looks like these settings are being overridden by /Users/steven/Sites/xxx/config/app.php.` but when I test the email, it always wants to go out via Mailgun rather than the local mail server configured for dev.

What have I missed here? My env has everything it needs and is in dev mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This caught me out too. It [says in the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#mailer-component) that

`Any changes you make to the Mailer component from config/app.php will not be reflected when testing email settings from Settings → Email.`

[image: Any changes you make to the Mailer component from config/app.php will not be reflected when testing email settings from Settings → Email.]

Comment: ‍♂️ good catch...I wasn't even referencing the Craft docs in this instance